# Qt - XQAlarm in Desktop versions

Tags: qt, qt4, meego

I'm starting to porting an Android app to Qt.  Planning to port it to MeeGo, Symbian and Linux-Windows desktop versions.

My app uses alarms in Android and I have found XQAlarm class in Qt to be very usefull, BUT its belongs to Mobile Extensions package.

Any equivalent class for desktop (Linux, Windows)? or a workarround class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for mobile extension, say Symbian, then you will have to use native OS API.

Sorry, by mistake I posted the reply here, instead of replying to : [How to set alarm in qt mobility application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704472/how-to-set-alarm-in-qt-mobility-application)

I was searching for similar questions on this site for "xqalarm" and got this hit.