# How to set alarm in qt mobility application

Tags: qt-creator

Is it possible to set an alarm for a specific time in Qt?

Comment: I think my qt sdk does not support XQAlarm APIs is there is any way to download it by outside if so plz tell me as i have to add alarm in my application and it is one of the most important part of my project

Comment: what version of qt are you using? how about giving a bit more info here?

Answer (score 2):

### Use extension class XQAlarm.

This is generally part of Mobile Extensions offered in the SDK for a given OS. For Symbian, for example, you can find it on http://forum.nokia.com. (Please note that they might have been deprecated by Nokia as it XQAlarm of Alarms API was released under "technology review" program only for Symbian community by Nokia).

Here is example how to use XQAlarm:

```
    // Creating a workday wakeup alarm 
    XQAlarms* alarms = new XQAlarms(this); 
    QDateTime alarmDateTime = alarmDateTime.currentDateTime();
    alarmDateTime.setTime(QTime(15, 0)); 
    // Create XQAlarm data object 
    XQAlarm weeklyReport; 
    weeklyReport.setExpiryTime(alarmDateTime); 
    weeklyReport.setMessage("Do weekly report"); 
    weeklyReport.setRepeatDefinition(XQAlarm::RepeatWeekly);
    alarms->addAlarm(weeklyReport);
```

Comment: I think XQAlarm is not supporting in my qt

Comment: is it symbian or android or something else?

Comment: Thanks 
Viren Shakya its workings. and vivek download latest version of Nokia Qt sdk...then you will surely get XQAlarm class

Comment: Glad that helped. :-) Could you please mind accepting the answer here by clicking on the "Accept" link above? :-)